# Here is issue while using spark bucket, how can I solve it?

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle, bucket

I have a serious question about spark buckets.

Is there a way to use it as a Dataset when using a spark bucket?

I'm trying to minimize shuffling by using buckets for large data and joins with other intermediate data.

However, when joining, joinWith is used on the dataset. When the bucketed table is read, it is a dataframe type, so when converted to a dataset, the bucket information disappears.

Is there a way to use Dataset's joinWith while retaining bucket information?

```
sample code

    val t1 = spark.read.table("bucketed_table").toDS() // can not reference bucket info
    val t2 = Seq(...).toDS() // intermediate data
    t1.joinWith(t2, t1("col") === t2("col"), "full_outer")
```